# Is there any equivalent to aws eip in azure? Apart from load balancer

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-virtual-machine, azure-public-ip

we have an active-passive server setup.So we want to allocate a public ip to active  server. We are able to do this in AWS using eip .Is there any feature which we can use in azure just like eip in aws?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 6):

You could use static Public IPs in Azure. You could associate a Public IP to a VM's NIC then change the IP address `assignment` to **static**. Also, Azure DNS allows you to reach this IP via a [Public custom DNS name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/portal-create-fqdn).

> We do support Static Public IPs in Azure today that is equivalent to
>   Elastic IP in AWS. Static Public IPs can be mapped to a VM’s NIC
>   (elastic IP equivalent) or to a load balancer’s Front end IP.

More details from the [Azure feedback.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/397428-create-elastic-ips-so-we-can-actually-create-web-a)

Apart for the Azure Load balancer, you may have interested in [Azure traffic manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/traffic-manager/traffic-manager-overview) which is a DNS-based traffic load balancer that enables you to distribute traffic optimally to services across global Azure regions, while providing high availability and responsiveness.